# PHP How can I set a default path to cookies

Tags: php, session, cookies

I'd like to know if there's anyway I can set default path to cookies, so I doesn't need to specify it on *setcookie* function call, I tried on php.ini file, but it's not working as I supposed.

When I check out my cookies on firebug, I get that: [FireBug PrintScreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XHC91.png)

I need both to be the same value, so if I put the code bellow on any file at "/loja", it works.

```
setcookie("PHPSESSID", $_COOKIE['PHPSESSID'], 0, "/");
```

But the problem is, I have the same code working on different areas, so I'm pretty sure it's something wrong on server side config.

I hope made myself clear, any insight about it would be great.

Answer (score 0):

You're making a mistake by manipulating phpsessid directly.
Use `session_name` instead:

```
session_name("sessionExampleName"); //Use diferent names for each application
session_start();
```

To get or set a session id:

```
//Set:
session_id('newid');
session_start();


//Get
session_start();
$id = session_id();
```

Comment: Actually, I need PHPSESSID to have the same value even on path "/" or "/loja", so it's a way to make it keep working.

Comment: I have updated my answer, please take a look @DaniloDeverso

Comment: Oh I see, but the real problem here is when I start session on subfolder named "loja", it's not available on root folder ("/"), I want to set a cookie with no path parameter, and it needs to be written always on "/" folder, even when it's called at subfolders.